# Matlab: Greek symbols using 'text' function

Tags: matlab

How to print a Greek symbol on a figure using the function `sprintf` in MATLAB?

I want to write an equation:

```
ε = C x²
```

on a MATLAB figure (not `x` and `y` label).

I tried:

```
C=60;
eq= sprintf('\epsilon = %d x^2',C);
text(x,y,eq)
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to escape `\`:

```
eq= sprintf('\\epsilon = %d x^2',C);
```